# Bubble Sort Doubly Link List

Tags: c++

I want to sort doubly link list using bubble sort. It is having loop problem and also the swap is not taking place properly.
The problem is the greatest number should be at the end after one iteration of i. But it doesn't and stop in between. I tried various options but could not solve it. Please help me solve this problem

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
        node *next;
        node *prev;
        int data;
        node(int x, node *p, node *n)
        {
            next = n;
            prev = p;
            data = x;
        }
};
class list{
    private:
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    public:
    list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void addtoend(int x)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = new node (x,NULL,NULL);
            tail = head;
        }
        else if(tail->prev == NULL)
        {
            tail = new node(x,head,NULL);
            head->next = tail;
        }
        else
        {
            node *temp = tail;
            tail = new node(x,tail,NULL);
            temp->next = tail;

        }
    }
    void bubblesort()
    {
        node *temp = head;
        node *temp2 = temp;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<"I: "<<i<<endl;
            temp = head;
            while(1)
            {
                temp2 = temp;
                if(temp->next->data < temp->data)
                {
                    if(temp == head)
                    {
                        cout<<"HEAD"<<endl;
                        head = head->next;
                        node *after = head->next;
                        head->prev = NULL;
                        temp->prev = head;
                        head->next = temp;
                        temp->next = after;
                        after->prev = temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp->next == tail)
                    {
                        cout<<"TAIL"<<endl;
                        node *back = temp->prev;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        tail->next = temp;
                        temp->prev = tail;
                        back->next = tail;
                        tail->prev = back;
                        tail = tail->next;
                        tail->next=NULL;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"ANY"<<endl;
                        node *back = temp->prev;
                        node *after = temp->next->next;

                        back->next=temp->next;
                        temp->prev = temp->next;
                        after->prev->next = temp;
                        after->prev->prev = back;
                        after->prev = temp;
                        temp->next = after;

                    }
                }
                display();
                display0();
                temp = temp2->next;
                cout<<"HEAD: "<<head->data<<endl;
                cout<<"Tail: "<<tail->data<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                if(temp->next->next== NULL)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    void display()
    {
        node *temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    void display0()
    {
        node *temp = tail;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
};
main()
{
    list l1;
    int x[10] = {17,15,8,12,10,5,4,1,7,2};
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        l1.addtoend(x[i]);
    }
    l1.display();
    l1.bubblesort();
    l1.display();
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: step through your code in your debugger..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am already added debugging lines but couldn't identify the error

Comment: Updated the code with some changes but still no answer

Comment: That's *not* what I said / what my point was.. Try actually using your debugger. Step through the code, pay attention to variable values and control flow. Note where it differs from your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How-to implement bubblesort algorithm for double-linked list

There are at least two ways to implement the bubblesort algorithm in `c++` for a *double-linked list*. Swapping the content aka the data of two neighbored nodes as shown under **I.** and re-wiring the pointers as shown under **II.**:

[image: Graphical solution of bubblesort]

The advantage of **II.** is that no temporary memory `temp2` is required. Therefore this is the preferred solution as stated also by the OP.

#### I. Swapping data

Just replace the OP `bubblesort` function by this one:

```cpp
    void bubblesort()
    {
        bool is_sorted = false;
        node *temp = head;
        while (!is_sorted)
        {
            is_sorted = true;
            temp = head;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                if(temp->next->data < temp->data)
                {
                    is_sorted = false;
                    int temp2 = temp->data;
                    temp->data = temp->next->data;
                    temp->next->data = temp2;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        display();
        display0();
    }
```

The algorithm uses a Boolean variable `is_sorted` to check if the sorting of the *double-linked list* is finished. Otherwise the bubbles are still rising. It swaps only the data values of the *double linked list*.

#### II. Re-wiring the pointers

This is the required solution for the OP and the preferred one:

```cpp
    void bubblesort()
    {
        bool is_sorted = false;
        node *temp = head;
        while (!is_sorted)
        {
            is_sorted = true;
            temp = head;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                if(temp->next->data < temp->data)
                {
                    is_sorted = false;
                    if(temp == head)
                    {
                        //temp->prev->next = temp->next; // 1. (impossible)
                        temp->next->prev = NULL;         // 2.
                        head = temp->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp->prev->next = temp->next;   // 1.
                        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;   // 2.
                    }
                    temp->prev = temp->next;             // 3.
                    if(temp->next == tail)
                    {
                        temp->next = NULL;               // 4.
                        tail = temp;
                        //temp->next->prev = temp2;      // 5. (impossible)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp->next = temp->next->next;   // 4.
                        temp->next->prev = temp;         // 5.
                    }
                    temp->prev->next = temp;             // 6.
                    temp = temp->prev;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        display();
        display0();
    }
```

#### Output

The output of the program with updated `bubblesort` functions is:

```
17 15 8 12 10 5 4 1 7 2
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 12 15 17
17 15 12 10 8 7 5 4 2 1
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 12 15 17
```

First line shows the input list without sorting. The second shows the sorting result in ascending order, while the third shows the descending order, which proves that the forward and reverse links of the list are still working.  The last line is the sorted list output in the `main` function.

The original order of the list is lost, of course.

The full source code is also available on [github](https://github.com/ckebar/SO58573297).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm... seems all the reverse links in the *doubly-linked list* would now be scrambled?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks for your hint. I've added the output in forward and reverse direction, which shows that the reverse links are still working.

Comment: Much better (but I would leave the `display()` and `display0()` for main() `:)` (and you may want to explain you are just swapping `int` values instead of re-wiring the pointers -- works fine for `int` data values, but the swap/copy costs go way up with a large number of class data members that must remain correlated to one another)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I totally agree to your comment. The swapping of the int values is a quite simple solution and shall not be applied to a large number of class data members. If the OP needs an answer with re-wiring of pointers, then he hopefully requests it. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: @CKE Our instructor told us that this is the rule that we should not swap data but swap the nodes. So i have to swap nodes. I have done that assignment by myself and by visualization on paper I got all the cases right. One if it's the head which is replacing. Second any middle node. Third if it's the tail. I will add code here. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Please have a look the solution with swapping as well as pointer re-wiring now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I submitted and it is working properly. I find my mistakes by creating a visual picture on paper. Also my instructor has instructed to swap nodes, in any question data swapping is not acceptable.

```
void bubblesort()
{
    node *temp = head;
    int len = length();
    for(int i=0;i<(len - 1);i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        temp = head;
        int c=0;
        while(c<(len - i - 1))
        {
            cout<<"Temp: "<<temp->data<<" ";
            cout<<"Temp: "<<temp->next->data<<" "<<endl;
            if(temp->next->data < temp->data)
            {
                if(temp == head)
                {
                    cout<<"HEAD"<<endl;
                    head = head->next;
                    node *after = head->next;
                    head->prev = NULL;
                    temp->prev = head;
                    head->next = temp;
                    temp->next = after;
                    after->prev = temp;
                    temp = head->next;
                }
                else if(temp->next == tail)
                {
                    cout<<"TAIL"<<endl;
                    node *back = temp->prev;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    tail->next = temp;
                    temp->prev = tail;
                    back->next = tail;
                    tail->prev = back;
                    tail = tail->next;
                    tail->next=NULL;
                    temp= tail;

                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"ANY"<<endl;
                    node *back = temp->prev;
                    node *after = temp->next->next;

                    back->next=temp->next;
                    temp->prev = temp->next;
                    after->prev->next = temp;
                    after->prev->prev = back;
                    after->prev = temp;
                    temp->next = after;
                    temp = after->prev;
                }
            }
            else
            temp = temp->next;
            display();
            display0();
            cout<<"HEAD: "<<head->data<<endl;
            cout<<"Tail: "<<tail->data<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            c++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite good that you find yourself the solution with pointer re-wiring. Please have a look on my solution. I also used a graphical way to understand the rewiring of the pointers.