# Doubly Linked List Triplets

Tags: c++

Stuck in C++.Hi, I am trying to find the consecutive sum of triplets in a Doubly linked list and here's my program. But while running it on the IDE (VS code) I am getting Segmentation Core Dumped error.
I am trying It using pointers who will traverse the list and given total count of such tripletes
Program:->

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
 public:
 int data;
 node* next,*prev;
};

void insert(node** head_ref,int data)
{
    node* new_node = new node();  
  
    new_node->data = data;   
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);  
    new_node->prev = NULL;  
  
    if ((*head_ref) != NULL)  
     (*head_ref)->prev = new_node;  
  
    (*head_ref) = new_node;  
}

void display(node* head)  
{  
    cout<<"\nTraversal in forward direction \n";  
    while (head != NULL)  
    {  
        cout<<" "<<head->data<<"<=>";    
        head = head->next;  
    }
}

void triplet(node* head,int j)
{
   node* nx;
   node* pr;
   int count=0;
   while(head->next!=NULL)
   {
       head=head->next;
       nx = head->next;
       pr = head->prev;
       cout<<"Insside while";
       if(nx->data+head->data+pr->data==j)
       {
           count++;
       }
   }    
    cout<<"\n"<<count;
}

int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    insert(&head,7);
    insert(&head,6);
    insert(&head,5);
    insert(&head,4);
    insert(&head,3);
    insert(&head,2);
    insert(&head,1);

    display(head);

    triplet(head,6);
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: `nx = head->next;` means that `nx` will be a null pointer when you reach the end of your list. You need to check for that before accessing `nx->data`

Comment: Same for prev, given that they're passing the head of the list. I mean, same for the head as well, since you don't want to run the operation on an empty list.

Comment: The best tool to find such problems is your debugger. VS Code has a decent debugger

Comment: Please have a look to this answer for [double-linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586056/9222996).

Comment: Consider renaming `head` in `triplet` ro `current` or something like that. It's not the head of the list more often than not, and even when it is `current` describes the purpose of the variable better than `head`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
   head=head->next;
   nx = head->next;
   pr = head->prev;
```

You are setting `head` before accesing `head->next`. Therefore, you end up dereferencing a null pointer. I mean, at the beginning `head->next` wasn't null but now it might.

You should also check for prev, which can be null the first time.

In fact, `head = head->next` should be the last thing you should do on each loop, like this:

```
void triplet(node* head,int j)
{
   node* nx;
   node* pr;
   int count=0;
   while(head->next!=NULL)
   {
       nx = head->next;
       pr = head->prev;
       cout<<"Insside while";
       if(pr && nx->data+head->data+pr->data==j)
       {
           count++;
       }
       head=head->next;
   }    
    cout<<"\n"<<count;
}
```

**Update:** You should also check for `head != NULL`. I didn't mention it before because in your program head is always not NULL (initialized before calling the function).

Comment: Note: Program may still be invalid. `head->next!=NULL` is checked, but `head` isn't. No `head`, no `head->next` and program breaks testing `head->next!=NULL`. You're usually better off iterating `while(head)`.

Comment: you are right, I ignored it before because of how the function is being called but it is worth mentioning.