# Double stack linked list segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I've been asked to make a C++ program Double stack with linked list. I can't find any tutorial or example on Google, most of them use Array to do it. so I have to figure it out how to do this, and end up with Segmentation Fault output in the end, which I still have no idea which part of my code is wrong here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
Node *head = NULL;
Node *tail = NULL;
Node *del = NULL;

void push(Node **head_ref, int data){
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    head->prev = temp;
    head = temp;
}

void push2(Node **head_ref, int data){
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    tail->next = temp;
    temp->prev = tail;
    tail = temp;
}

void pop(Node **head_ref, int data){
    del = head;
    head->next->prev = NULL;
    head = del->next;
    del = NULL;
}

void pop2(Node **head_ref, int data){
    del = tail;
    tail->prev->next = NULL;
    tail = del->prev;
    del = NULL;
}

int peek(Node **head_ref){
    return head->data;
}

int main(){
    system("clear");
    push2(&head, 10);
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: In `main`: `push2(&head, 10);` : `head` is `NULL`, so what do you expect?

Comment: in `push2` you access `tail->next`, but tail is NULL at this point. Also - what's the purpose of `system("clear")` ?

Comment: @wohlstad `system("clear");` probably clears the screen on the OP's system.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is it recomended to call `system("clear")` from within a running process ? I think in Windows it creates another process (cmd.exe) to run the command, and in this case I thought it will clear the console of the child process. Unless they share the console.

Comment: @wohlstad, in Windows cmd it would have to be `system("cls")`, in powershell both work. It doesn't create another process, it simply clears the console. It's not thread safe though, the system call.

Comment: @wohlstad `system("clear");` does create another process, but as it runs in the same console it just works fine. Anyway `system("clear");` is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Your functions are supposed to use the `head_ref` argument.

Comment: hmmm I want to focus on ```push``` only
So if I replace ```head->prev = NULL;``` with ```temp->prev = NULL;``` that works but that's a Double Linked list and I am not sure if Double stack is just a Double linked list type with different variable names etc.

Comment: also the reason I put ```system("clear");``` at the beginning of main code is because I am too lazy to clear my terminal after finished running the program. and yes for Windows user, you need to replace it with ```system("cls")```

Comment: Please have a look at this answer regarding [double linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586056/9222996). Maybe you can take the whole post as template as well as the information from github?